# fullpage.js - Preview of upper and bottom page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to use fullpage.js (https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) in order to realize a website with a particular section slider, with the requirement that the sections do not use the full height of the website.

This is a demo of the effect: 
[gif demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O22yG.gif)

I'm using the fp-auto-height option in order to realize the effect. The problem is I would like to give a preview of both the upper and the lower section's image, when I'm on a section, and I'd like to vertically center the active section.

The text that is on the top and on the bottom of the section would then appear after I scroll to a certain section, and therefore the previews should regard only the image and not the relative text.

The creator of the script advised me to ask here since it's a matter of CSS, but I've tried multiple combinations and still couldn't find a good solution.

Comment: Why not just having full-screen sections but just adding a top and bottom black elements inside each section to simulate that?

Comment: How could this solve the problem? I tried multiple things and I don't understand how I can realize the gif demo. If you may help me building an example (maybe via jsfiddle), that would be fantastic